# The order of an element in a direct sum

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I have a quick question:

Say I have $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_5$ and I want to find the order of an element, say $(3,4)$.

Well, in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, the order of 3 is equal to: $4/\gcd(3,4)=4$

In $\mathbb{Z}_5$ the order of 4 is equal to: $5/\gcd(4,5)=5$

So the total order is $\text{lcm}(4,5)=20$?

Comment: this one is correct.

Comment: so in general, the form I use is: If I have$\mathbb{Z}_a \oplus \mathbb{Z}_b \oplus \mathbb{Z}_c......$and I have the element $(x_1,x_2,x_3,....)$ then I find the orders of each element in is respective group then I take the LCM of all those orders?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: One can think  of $3$ as $(3,0)$ and $4$ as $(0,4)$. Then $(3,4)$ is the sum. If the orders of $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then the order of the sum $a+b$ is the product of the orders.

Comment: ah very good. Thanks Anurag and Andre!